# Alexander Method for non-orientable Surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

From Farb and Margalit,Primer on Mapping Class Group, p.62, we know
[image]

For example for torus with four puncture we can choose following claret red curves. Curves are choosen such that their complement is disjoint union of discs or one punctured discs:
[image]

Is this method valid for non-orientable surfaces? If yes, I can not choose curves satisfying especially the third condition.